# WinProc() vs main message loop

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I noticed that some messages in WinAPI can be retrieved only in the "main message loop" with `PeekMessage()` (like `WM_QUIT`), others can only be retrieved in the user defined `winProc()` function (like `WM_CLOSE` and `WM_SIZE`), and some messages like `WM_MOUSEMOVE` are retrieved with both.

What's the difference? How do I know where the WM message is going to be sent to?

Comment: Some messages aren't actually pushed into the queue normally but is generated on demand when needed [More information here: Raymond Chen - Even though mouse-move, paint, and timer messages are generated on demand, it’s still possible for one to end up in your queue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130523-00/?p=4273/). That may account for it.

Comment: By "queue" you mean the message loop? (PeekMessage())

Comment: PeekMessage and similar retrieves messages from a queue, but they can also generate messages that were never actually put in the queue to begin with. Typical messages are things like mouse movement etc. If you had a very fast computer you would get tons of mouse movement messages if you moved the mouse very fast over a component and the message loop wasn't actually processing, instead they defer until someone actually try to pull a message from the queue and generates 1 such message.

Comment: There really isn't any need to know. Any message (other than `WM_QUIT`) is passed to your window procedure when using a standard message loop. Whether a `WM_TIMER` or `WM_PAINT` message is generated on demand, doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: The message loop is basically just a loop that calls GetMessage and WndProc - [Wikipedia: Message loop in Microsoft Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows).

Comment: @IInspectable Is it legit to not listen for a WM_QUIT message at all in the message loop, but rather handle WM_CLOSE messages in the window procedure the same way?

Comment: Also, the window procedure function runs **after** `DispatchMessage()` is called, right?

Comment: From my checking I see that the window procedure actually runs (twice?) before each DispatchMessage() call. What..?

Comment: The window procedure is called before `GetMessage` (and relatives) return, in case there are any cross-thread sent messages pending. In that case, the message retrieval functions **dispatch** cross-thread sent (not posted) messages. `DispatchMessage` calls the window procedure. It is legal to handle each an every message in the message loop, as well as passing it on to the window procedure. It may not make for the cleanest code to handle `WM_CLOSE` both in the message loop as well as the window procedure, but it is legal to do so, if your architecture demands this.

Comment: The link @Lasse3 V. Karlsen's posted above is dead.  Working one: [Raymond Chen - Even though mouse-move, paint, and timer messages are generated on demand, it’s still possible for one to end up in your queue](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130523-00/?p=4273).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Messages that were posted with a NULL window handle can only be retrieved in the message loop.  Necessarily so, DispatchMessage() can't do its job.  This is quite rare.

But yes, WM_QUIT, note how [PostQuitMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not take a window handle.  That's rather inevitable, when you call PostQuitMessage() you (usually) don't have any window left so only a NULL window handle is sensible.  Of course its real intention is to make GetMessage() return FALSE and thus terminate the message loop.

The only other case I can think of are messages generated with [PostThreadMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Note how this is a pretty dangerous function, it should never be used to post messages to a thread that ever displays any window.  Such messages fall in the bit-bucket when another message loop pumps.  Like the one that allows the user to move/resize a window.  Or the one that keeps MessageBox() modal.  It is only useful in process and thread interop marshaling.

So just ignore this, it is a corner-case.